# Call method with new parameter values for each loop in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, loops

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ShowDetailRate(FormCollection form)
    {
        List<Calculation> finalList = new List<Calculation>();
        Calculation calc3 = new Calculation();
        double InterestRate = 0;
        double guess = 0.01;
        double guess2 = 0.03;
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            InterestRate = secantInterestRate(guess, guess2, form);
            if (radio == "inArrears")
            {
                radioCalc = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                radioCalc = InvoiceAmount;
            }
            calc3.PeriodStartDate = PeriodStartDate;
            calc3.PeriodEndDate = PeriodEndDate;
            if (DTC == "365/365")
            {
                calc3.NumberOfDays = Convert.ToInt32((calc3.PeriodEndDate - calc3.PeriodStartDate).Days) + 1;
            }
            else if (DTC == "360/360")
            {
                calc3.NumberOfDays = 30;
            }
            calc3.InvoiceAmount = InvoiceAmount;
            calc3.InterestRate = InterestRate;
            calc3.InterestAmount = (PV - radioCalc) * InterestRate / DTCyear * calc3.NumberOfDays;
            calc3.Amortization = (calc3.InvoiceAmount - calc3.InterestAmount);
            calc3.PresentValue = PV - calc3.Amortization;
            calc3.StartValue = PV;
            finalList.Add(calc3);
            var count = finalList.Count();
            if (finalList[count].PresentValue != FV)
            {
                guess = guess2;
                guess2 = calc3.InterestRate;
                continue;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        return PartialView("ShowDetail", finalList);
    }
```

In my method above I'm using my variable `InterestRate` to call a method called `secantInterestRate` with 3 parameters (`double`, `double`, `FormCollection`). The first round for the loop I want the first 2 parameters to be set as they are (0.01, 0.03), but in the second  loop-round I want `guess = guess 2`, and `guess2 = calc3.InterestRate`. And still be calling the method `secantInterestRate` in the beginning of the loop but with the new values. I have tried with a small if in the end:

```
var count = finalList.Count() - 3;
            if (finalList[count].PresentValue != FV)
            {
                guess = guess2;
                guess2 = calc3.InterestRate;
                continue;
            }
            else
                break;
```

But this don't work because when the loop starts over `guess` will be 0.01 and `guess2` will be 0.03 again, and not like I want it.

Is it possible to make `guess = guess2` and `guess2 = calc3.InterestRate` for every new round in the loop?

Comment: do you want to use the 0.01 and 0.03 values on the first round only and then `guess = guess2` and `guess2 = calc3.InterestRate` for the rest?

Comment: yes, thats exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
if (i==0) { 
  guess = guess2;
  guess2 = calc3.InterestRate;
} else { 
  // you don't want to change the values after the first time through; do nothing
}
```

PS: I suggest you factor out the calculation code from the form-processing code, or in some other way make the method more readable. Currently it's really hard to see the logic as there's so many lines of code, and that's probably the main reason it's hard to solve any small problems like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code according to the following:

```
....
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
          guess = guess2;
          guess2 = calc3.InterestRate;
    }
    InterestRate = secantInterestRate(guess, guess2, form);
...
```

Comment: But how can I set guess2 = calc3.InterestRate if it's calculated in secantInterestRate()?

Comment: The `guess2 = calc3.InterestRate` line will be executed after the first round (this is done by that `if (i > 0)`), so you will have the `calc3.InterestRate` already there because that variable was declared outside the loop.